# Can not Access Aliased Columns in Select Statement (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, alias

I have a problem with Aliased Columns in MySQL!
My Query:

```
SELECT Price AS Pr, (Pr*10/100) FROM MyTable;
```

MySQL WorkBench Error: **UnKnown Column 'Pr' in Field List** !!!

I tested my query in [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_alias_column) with no error !

Comment: You need to access the column with original name `SELECT Price AS Pr, (Price*10/100) FROM MyTable;`

Comment: I know, but actually my first column is something like `SUM(Price1*Price2*Coef1*Coef2)` and I wanted to make it easier!

Comment: Please don't reference w3schools as a resource.  See:  http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tested my query in W3Schools with no error!

This doesn't prove that your query is valid.

You can only use aliases in `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY` or `HAVING` clauses. Your usage variant is not allowed, because the value of alias is not known when MySQL is selecting the 2-nd column.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a suspicion that W3Schools uses MS Access to run user queries, and MS Access does allow such atrocity as referencing column aliases in a SELECT clause that are defined in the same SELECT clause.

The standard doesn't allow this and MySQL does follow standard in this particular case.

As for solution to your problem, I can see two options.

The more generic solution, which would run in probably any SQL product, would be to use a derived table:

```
SELECT
  Pr,
  (Pr * 10 / 100) AS SomethingElse
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      SomeComplexExpression AS Pr
    FROM MyTable
  ) AS sub
;
```

The other option would be to use a variable, which is MySQL-specific:

```
SELECT
  @Pr := SomeComplexExpression AS Pr,
  (@Pr * 10 / 100) AS SomethingElse
FROM MyTable
;
```

Finally, if you need to test/demonstrate if something can/cannot work in MySQL, I'd recommend using [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).